# Facade vs Laravel Real-time Facade

Tags: php, laravel

What is Facade vs Real-time Facades?

Just not getting How is Realtime facade is differnt form facade in laravel as well as its working.
Wondered at Google.com + stackoverflow but unable to get any proper satisfying anwser.

Comment: https://asklagbox.com/blog/laravel-realtime-facades